Non-manual method for enclosed space to closed mesh
Generally, what is a non-manual way to go from messy geometry that fully encloses a space, to a proper closed (manifold) mesh.
This could include removing self intersections, healing meshes, making manifold volumes from loose planes, resolving intersecting manifolds, and maybe everything at the same time.

Join all relevant geometry and enter edit mode on the joined object. Then run the code below in Blender's scripting window/workspace. See the end of this post for handling cavities and if too much of your mesh gets deleted. The steps are also listed below if you want to do it manually.
import bmesh
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') # enter edit mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # Select all
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split(type='EDGE') # Split faces by edges
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect(mode='SELECT') # Face intersect (knife)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # Select all
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles() # Merge by distance
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE") # Enter edge select mode

obj = bpy.context.object # Get the active object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data) # Access the BMesh of the object
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # Select all
bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop() # Select boundary loop
bm.select_flush_mode() # Update BMesh to reflect current edit mode state
while any(e.select for e in bm.edges):
  bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='EDGE') # Delete edges
  bpy.ops.mesh.select_loose() # Select loose geometry
  bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='EDGE') # Delete edges
  bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # Select all
  bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop() # Select boundary loop
  bm.select_flush_mode() # Update BMesh to reflect current edit mode state

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE") # Enter face select mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # Select all
bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False) # Recalculate normals (outside)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselect all
bpy.ops.mesh.select_interior_faces() # Select interior faces
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED') # Separate selection
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') # enter object mode



Select all relevant objects and join them (CTRL+J)
Select the joined object and enter edit mode (TAB)
Select all (A)
Split faces by edges (ALT+M -> "faces by edges")
Knife Intersect (CTRL+F -> "intersect (knife)" -> use options "self intersect", "cut", "exact")
Select all (A)
Merge by distance (M -> "by distance")
Enter edge select mode
Repeat in a loop until boundary loops are no longer getting selected:

Select all (A)
Select -> Select Loops -> Select Boundary Loops
Delete edges (DEL -> "edges")
Select -> Select All By Trait -> Loose Geometry
Delete edges (DEL -> "edges")


Select all (A)
Recalculate normals (ALT+N -> "Recalculate Outside")
Enter face select mode
Deselect all (ALT+A)
Select -> Select All By Trait -> Interior Faces
Separate selection (P -> "Selection")

This process wont remove valid cavities in your object. If you want to remove cavities it will be manual work and I suggest using separate by loose parts.
If a chunk of your mesh that you wanted to keep gets deleted, it means the conglomerate of objects has a hole(s) in it somewhere. You will have to manually fix this. I suggest manually following the steps above until you've done step 9.2 . At this point the hole(s) that needs filling will be somewhere among the selected edges. You'll have to manually find and fill the holes... good luck...

I don't know which version you are using or if you have custom shortcuts, but step 5 Alt+F is not Intersect (Knife), it is Fill, at least in all versions I have here (2.83.20, 3.1.2, 3.6.9, 4.0.2, 4.1.1, 4.2.1) and if someone is not paying close attention to your GIF or just reads the explanations, he might easily miss the point that you have to switch to Self Intersect since this is not the default.

Good catch. I made the edits.
